# Magento 2 Customer account custom tab not loading properly

Tags: magento2, frontend, customer-account

I'm trying to add a custom tab to the Customer account page. I followed the Mageplaza guide [here](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/add-custom-tab-customer-account-magento-2.html), however I'm having two issues.

First the menu item is added properly, but it points to routename/customer/index/ instead of the correct path (I changed it in the customer_account.xml file).

If type out the correct link, the page loads, but it bring up my second issue.
On the page I'm getting an undefined error:

> Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined property: Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::$getProductCollection in D:\xampp73\htdocs\testm2\app\code\Msquared\CustPriceRange\view\frontend\templates\custpricerange.phtml on line 22

Here's a link to the module [GitHub repo](https://github.com/msquaredstl/Crimson).

I'm running a local XAMPP copy of M2.3.4 on PHP 7.3.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check my answer. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/303841/59677

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have created module the same as this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/msquaredstl/Crimson). you have to update the below code in your

> app/code/Msquared/CustPriceRange/view/frontend/layout/custpricerange_customer_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <update handle="customer_account" />

   <head>
      <script src="Msquared_CustPriceRange::js/cpr.js" />
   </head>

   <body>
      <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
         <action method="setPageTitle">
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom Price Range</argument>
         </action>
      </referenceBlock>
      <referenceContainer name="content">
         <block class="Msquared\CustPriceRange\Block\CustPriceRange" name="custpricerange" template="Msquared_CustPriceRange::custpricerange.phtml">
         </block>
      </referenceContainer>
   </body>
</page>
```

Hope this will work for you.